# Why did this question get locked on Super User?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, locked

After solving a puzzling problem with my new computer, I posted the issue on SuperUser.com

> [How to get an Acer Aspire Revo to connect to the wireless keyboard and mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/72445/how-to-get-an-acer-aspire-revo-to-connect-to-the-wireless-keyboard-and-mouse)

As [recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not) , I answered my own question.

The question turned out to be popular (1k views), three people upvoted the answer I gave.

Today I returned to the question to find it locked. Searching on meta for locked questions, I cannot figure out why it is locked. There:

- Were no negative reactions to the question
- Was no excessive editing (I'm not sure if it was edited at all)
- Was no history of closing or flagging the question
- Was no gaming of the system (I wasn't responsible for the 1k views)

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-question-in-stackoverflow-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 7):

It was locked due to the spam it generated. There are currently a few deleted answers which were simply Thank You or Me Too.

High view questions that generate a lot of spam are locked periodically to ease the pressure a bit. This is done only on SU since some questions get a lot of views due to the topic being extremely popular for a period of time and they tend to attract a lot of spam answers.

I have unlocked the question again.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a comment when locking a question...

Comment: @ChrisF - Fair comment. However I locked that question a while ago, the OP only asked about it now? I probably did it at a stage I was dealing with a lot of queries and sometimes I did forget to comment. However the current and future SU moderators do comment when they lock as it is required. Since even moderators can only comment on a post when it is unlocked, it is actually easier to handle these directly when they come up here.

Comment: Does the FAQ question I linked to in my other comment need to be updated? It says that a locked question can still have answers added to it.

Comment: @Jon. Yes. Jeff changed that in the last 4 months. Can't remember exactly when. I have updated the FAQ.

Comment: @Diago: i don't think anyone's criticizing your actions (at least in this case).  thanks for taking the time to explain what happened here.  (for the record, the question in question generated 5 "me too" answers from new 1-rep users.  at least this shows @dggoldst's question and answer have been helpful!)

Comment: Please don't think I was criticising you. I was just trying to say it would be good if you could - under the assumption that there isn't a way you can easily comment at the moment.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Lock reason notices can be added to a post when locking it, and questions are *protected*, not locked, to prevent new users from answering.